# Sort filenames in an Array descending by most recent date/time created

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm building a master array of all the files in multiple image galleries and I want the images to display in descending order by date/time created. I need help with implementing `OrderBy` in my script. Is that the proper way to do it? I could really use some guidance.

```
// Build Gallery Array
        string[] arctopithecusImages = Directory.GetFiles(arctopithecusGalleryPath, "*.jpg");
        string[] gulonImages = Directory.GetFiles(gulonGalleryPath, "*.jpg");
        string[] scythianWolfImages = Directory.GetFiles(scythianWolfGalleryPath, "*.jpg");
        string[] simivulpaImages = Directory.GetFiles(simivulpaGalleryPath, "*.jpg");
        string[] succorathImages = Directory.GetFiles(succorathGalleryPath, "*.jpg");
        string[] tatusImages = Directory.GetFiles(tatusGalleryPath, "*.jpg");

        // Concatenate Gallery Folders into single Array
        galleryImages = 
            Directory.GetFiles(arctopithecusGalleryPath, "*.jpg")
                .Concat(gulonImages)
                .Concat(scythianWolfImages)
                .Concat(simivulpaImages)
                .Concat(succorathImages)
                .Concat(tatusImages).OrderBy(f => f.All)
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `DirectoryInfo` class. It will give you more than just the file name. and then you will be able to order by file properties

```
DirectoryInfo diArctopithecusDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(arctopithecusGalleryPath);
FileInfo[] arctopithecusImages = diArctopithecusDirectory.GetFiles("*.jpg");

DirectoryInfo diGulonImagesDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(gulonGalleryPath);
FileInfo[] arctopithecusImages = diGulonImagesDirectory.GetFiles("*.jpg");

DirectoryInfo diScythianWolfDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(scythianWolfGalleryPath);
FileInfo[] scythianWolfImages = diScythianWolfDirectory.GetFiles("*.jpg");

FileInfo[]  result = arctopithecusImages.Union(arctopithecusImages)
                    .Union(scythianWolfImages)
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime)
                    .ToArray();
```

If you just need the file names you could do something like

```
string[] result = arctopithecusImages.Union(arctopithecusImages)
                                    .Union(scythianWolfImages)
                                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime)
                                    .Select(x => x.Name)
                                    .ToArray();
```